# GWT - enable button on KeyDownEvent in RichTextArea

Tags: gwt, richtextarea

I have following handler

```
textArea.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
                //here
            }
        });
```

I need to enable save button with id "idsave", but I am not able to refer the button.
I am new to GWT, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code of  save button? Do you have the reference of the save button?

Comment: Is the issue resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have the reference of the button then try with the id.

```
// get element by id
Element saveButtonElement = RootPanel.get("idsave").getElement(); 

// remove disabled attribute to make it enable
saveButtonElement.removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you do not use element ids in GWT. If you created a button, you can simply use it:

```
private Button saveButton;
...

saveButton = new Button("Save");
textArea.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {
     @Override
     public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
          saveButton.setEnabled(true);
     }
});
```

Comment: OP says *but I am not able to refer the button*

Comment: Can't refer `saveButton` inside `KeyDownHandler` because button is not `final`.